# how to make an entire row as a link using jquery in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>S.no</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Points</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="next.html">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>random</td>
            <td>91</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have used the following code to add multiple rows using jquery

```
function tablename() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
        tr.addClass("clickable-row");
        tr.attr('data-href', 'link.html');
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var td = $("<td></td>").text("dilkush");
            tr.append(td);
        }
        $("tbody").append(tr);
    });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function () {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

the function "tablename()" is called after the body is been loaded (`<body onload("tablename();")>`)...
in the table the all the fields are added but when I click over it  does not move to the next page...
I have used bootstrap you someone please figure out the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically added elements

Instead of:

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function () {
```

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
$(document).on('click', ".clickable-row", function () {
```

---

Even better practice is to add an `id` attribute to the table `<table id="my-table">` and then:

```
$('#my-table').on('click', ".clickable-row", function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to call function on body load is as below:

```
<body onload="functionname()">
```

Do not keep `$(document).ready()` inside a named `function`. So either use `function` which could be called on `body load` or use `$(document).ready` without wrapping it in a `function` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
        tr.addClass("clickable-row");
        tr.attr('data-href', 'link.html');
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var td = $("<td></td>").text("dilkush");
            tr.append(td);
        }
        $("tbody").append(tr);
});
```

Now since the `element` with classname `clickable-row` is added dynamically you need to do event delegation. Say your `table` has `id`= `table1`. Event delegation will be as follows:

```
$('#table1').on('click',".clickable-row",function () {
      window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

on click of table row class, assign the location href to clicked row href

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function(){
    location.href = $(this).data("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your click event on the go.

Here is the fix.

```
$(".clickable-row").on('click',function () {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
```